# TYPO3 Extbase ConfigurationManager getContentObject deprecated

Tags: typo3, extbase

There is this code in my extension

```
$data = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;
```

But the code is deprecated

```
/**
 * @deprecated since v12. Remove in v13.
 */
public function getContentObject(): ?ContentObjectRenderer;
```

How can i retrieve the data?

Edit:

```
$data = ($versionInformation->getMajorVersion() > 12) ?
        $this->request->getAttribute('currentContentObject')->data :
        $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;
```

works.

Comment: Have a look: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.4/Deprecation-100662-ConfigurationManager-getContentObject.html